# How to create dummy variables on Ordinal columns in Python

Tags: pandas, python-3.6, one-hot-encoding

I am new to Python. I have created dummy columns on categorical column using pandas get_dummies. How to create dummy columns on ordinal column (say column Rating has values 1,2,3...,10)

Comment: Could you provide an example input and output? If your values are already numeric what would the dummy variables be?

Comment: Colx  Rating  Rating_1 Rating_2 Rating_3
a        1      1         0           0
a        1      1         0           0
b        2      0         1           0
c        3      0         0           1
c        3      0         0           1
Say I want to create the columns Rating_1, Rating_2, Rating_3 from Rating Column

Answer (score 2):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Cats=list('abcdcba'), Ords=[3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3]))
df

  Cats  Ords
0    a     3
1    b     2
2    c     1
3    d     0
4    c     1
5    b     2
6    a     3
```

***`pd.get_dummies`***
*works the same on either column*
**with `df.Cats`**

```
pd.get_dummies(df.Cats)

   a  b  c  d
0  1  0  0  0
1  0  1  0  0
2  0  0  1  0
3  0  0  0  1
4  0  0  1  0
5  0  1  0  0
6  1  0  0  0
```

**with `df.Ords`**

```
   0  1  2  3
0  0  0  0  1
1  0  0  1  0
2  0  1  0  0
3  1  0  0  0
4  0  1  0  0
5  0  0  1  0
6  0  0  0  1
```

**with both**

```
pd.get_dummies(df)

   Ords  Cats_a  Cats_b  Cats_c  Cats_d
0     3       1       0       0       0
1     2       0       1       0       0
2     1       0       0       1       0
3     0       0       0       0       1
4     1       0       0       1       0
5     2       0       1       0       0
6     3       1       0       0       0
```

Notice that it split out `Cats` but not `Ords`

Let's expand on this by adding another `Cats2` column and calling `pd.get_dummies`

```
pd.get_dummies(df.assign(Cats2=df.Cats)))

   Ords  Cats_a  Cats_b  Cats_c  Cats_d  Cats2_a  Cats2_b  Cats2_c  Cats2_d
0     3       1       0       0       0        1        0        0        0
1     2       0       1       0       0        0        1        0        0
2     1       0       0       1       0        0        0        1        0
3     0       0       0       0       1        0        0        0        1
4     1       0       0       1       0        0        0        1        0
5     2       0       1       0       0        0        1        0        0
6     3       1       0       0       0        1        0        0        0
```

Interesting, it splits both `object` columns but not the numeric one.

Comment: This is a good solution. If I understand correctly I think in this case Pandas has no way of knowing that the numeric column is ordinal and not an interval or continuous data, in which case it doesn't make sense to create dummy variables. Converting the `Ords` column to strings: `df.Ords = df.Ords.astype(str)` should split out all of the data into dummy variables?

Comment: @johnchase if you run `pd.get_dummies` on an ordinal column, it works as expected.  I was surprised to see that pandas makes a distinction when running `pd.get_dummies` on a dataframe.

Comment: @piRSquared: Thanks for your reply. That's what I observed, when I used pd.get_dummies(df),it does dummy coding on only categorical columns. I have multiple Ordinal columns and I wish to create the dummy columns on those in one go if possible.